# Exit not behaving the same as Exit-PSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/exit-pssession?view=powershell-6) says:

> Example 3: Use the Exit keyword to stop a session
>
> `PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -computername Server01
>   Server01\PS> exit
>   PS C:\>`
>
> This example uses the Exit keyword to stop an interactive
>   session started by using Enter-PSSession. The Exit keyword has the
>   same effect as using Exit-PSSession.

This implies `Exit` is equivalent to `Exit-PSSession`.

However, `Exit` is not behaving identically to `Exit-PSSession`.

For example, the following outputs "blah" :

```
Exit-PSSession
Write-Host "blah"
```

But this does not :

```
Exit
Write-Host "blah"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: that `exit` does what `Exit-PSSession` can do ... does NOT mean the the reverse is true. [*grin*]

Comment: I've updated your question to include the example code that accompanies the reference you used.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was under the impressions that `Exit` was an alias for `Exit-PSSession`, however I've just realised there is a cmdlet `Get-Alias`, and it's not listed in there.

Comment: @FiretopWarlock: more generally you can use `Get-Command` with any command name to see its definition (whether the name refers to an executable, cmdlet, alias, function, or `*.ps1` file); however, that doesn't work with language keywords such as `exit`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the further clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PowerShell session is not a *remote* one that was entered with `Enter-PSSession`, `Exit-PSSession` is a quiet no-op, i.e., quietly does *nothing*.

By contrast, `exit` works in both local and remote sessions.

In other words:

- Use of `Exit-PSSession` is only meaningful in *remote* sessions<sup>[1]</sup>, and
- only there is `exit` its equivalent.

To put it yet another way:

- The `Exit-PSSession` seems to exist primarily for symmetry with `Enter-PSSession`.
- You may opt to only ever use `exit`, which has the advantage of working in *local* sessions too.

---

As for whether the *PS session on the remote computer* itself *continues to exist* (note that up to PSv2 remote sessions lived only on the *client* computer):

That depends on how it was initially created:

- If the session was *implicitly* created by passing a computer name to `Enter-PSSession`  (`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ...`), it will be automatically closed and discarded on exiting the session (irrespective of whether you used `exit` or `Exit-PSSession`).
- By contrast, if you *explicitly* created a session with `New-PSSession` first and passed that to `Enter-PSSession` (`Enter-PSSession -Session ...`), it will continue to exist and remain open after you exit the *interactive* session (again, irrespective of the exit method), so it can be reentered later (or reused with `Invoke-Command`, for instance).

`Get-PSSession` lists the sessions explicitly created locally; `Get-PSSession -ComputerName ...` lists a given remote computer's sessions.

---

<sup>[1] As implied by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/exit-pssession?view=powershell-6) stating (emphasis added): "Ends an interactive session with a *remote* computer." and "The `Exit-PSSession` cmdlet ends interactive sessions *that you started by using the `Enter-PSSession` cmdlet*.</sup>

Comment: I want to emphasize this one more time. **EXIT** kills remote sessions. `State - Closed; Availability - None`

Comment: @it3xl: Please see my update (behavior verified in WinPS v5.1 and PS Core v7.0-preview 5). However, I'm not sure what you're trying to make clear: yes, exiting an _implicitly_ created session - whether with `exit` or `Exit-PSSession` - automatically closes and discards it, but that's to be expected; An _explicitly_ created session should live on in the opened state - are you using an _older_ PS version, and if so, which, and do you know when the behavior changed? P.S.: Why _one more time_?

Comment: I'm used to using `Exit <non-0-num>` to interrupt loudly in shells and CMD. I got in a trouble with this habit in PowerShell Remoting. It looks like I have to use `Throw` instead.